# How to copy bytes from bytesource to bytesink

Tags: java, guava

I am using guava version 19.0. Initially i was using input supplier and output supplier, but then i upgraded my guava version from 15.0 to 19.0 and input supplier and output supplier is deprecated now, so i started using bytesource and bytesink, but then while using "ByteStreams.copy(input, output)" i am getting this error "cannot resolve method copy(com.google.io.bytesource,com.google.iobytesink)"

```js
ByteSource input = Resources.asByteSource(URI.create(url).toURL());
ByteSink output = Files.asByteSink(zipTemp);

ByteStreams.copy(input,output);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `copyTo` from `ByteSource` (see [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html#copyTo(com.google.common.io.ByteSink))).

```
input.copyTo(output).
```